# Connecting MySQL to external data source using proprietary ODBC Driver

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc, servicenow

I have a cloud-based CRM system that provides a proprietary [ODBC Driver](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=ODBC_Driver).
This has been fully configured, set up as a system DSN, and tested with no errors. The system DSN is called 'servicenowdev'.

I also have a local MySQL server, that I would like to connect to the CRM system and download periodic backups. I can connect to the 'servicenowdev' DSN using i-SQL and run queries fine, but I would like to link the server (MS SQL Server "Linked Server" style), but in MySQL.

- Where do I start with connecting my MySQL server to this dsn?
  I don't know the internal details of the CRM system to provide a database name, host, port or any other details for a FEDERATED SERVER connection.
- Can I create views straight to the dsn's tables, or would I have to import data locally?

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative, albeit not the most efficient, method.  In essence I start with MS Access by creating pass through query using the

```
ServiceNow ODBC. (SELECT * FROM servicenow.table)
```

I then perform an insert query into a local access table using the pass through query as the source

```
(INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM query)
```

Then I export the table to the MySQL database using the MySQL ODBC.

Hoping you've found a better method but if not then hope this helps.

Comment: I removed your question (which is better reserved for comments) but left the answer portion. Answers should always answer the question